# Load HTML after page load

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, html-agility-pack

I have htmltable like this the image below. My task is to export the table to excel. After the table bind, I use HTML agility pack together to scrape the table.

[image]

So my code is like below

```
    Dim webclient As MyWebClient = New MyWebClient()
    Dim url2 = New Uri(Request.Url, "dailyig.aspx").AbsoluteUri
    Dim page As String = webclient.DownloadString(url2)
    Dim doc As HtmlDocument = New HtmlDocument()
    Dim dsHtml As New DataSet
    doc.LoadHtml(page)



    Dim tables = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table//tr") _
            .GroupBy(Function(x) x.Ancestors("table").First())
```

I have problem when want to load html, the page load have session and it will redirect to "logout.html". How to solve this? I want the html table only. Below is my Page_Load

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim loginid As String = Session("EmployeeID")

    If loginid = "" Then
        Response.Redirect("~/logout.html")
    End If

    qaaMonDailyIG = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyyMM")
    qaaDayDailyIG = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).ToString("dd")
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        bindData()
    End If

End Sub
```